# How to parse only 'kwargs' and skip args when calling PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am calling a function which takes a list of positional arguments followed by keyword arguments. I want to process args and kwargs both separately. Unfortunately, unlike PyArg_ParseTuple for positional arguments, there is no equivalent PyArg_ParseKeywords for keyword arguments. I tried to prevent parsing of positional arguments by passing Py_None (also NULL) in place of args:

```
static PyObject* test_func(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    static const char *kwList[] = {"kw1", "kw2", NULL};
    const char* kw1_val = NULL;
    PyObject* kw2_val = NULL;

    if (! PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(Py_None, 
                                      kwargs,
                                      "zO",
                                      const_cast<char**>(kwList),
                                      &kw1_val,
                                      &kw2_val))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Having Py_None (or NULL) there leads to :

```
Python/getargs.c:1390: bad argument to internal function
```

If I replace Py_None by args, I get following error:

```
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Above TypeError occurs as it unpacks 2 positional args and 2 keyword args I passed to test_func while there are only two variables, kw1_val and kw2_val to receive those 4 values in parsing method.

Is there a way to handle above scenario ? Note that positional argument can have any number of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing an empty tuple instead of `Py_None`:

```c
static PyObject* test_func(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    static const char *kwList[] = {"kw1", "kw2", NULL};
    const char* kw1_val = NULL;
    PyObject* kw2_val = NULL;

    PyObject *retvalue = NULL;
    PyObject *empty = PyTuple_New(0);

    if (empty == NULL){
        goto out;
    }

    if (! PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(empty, 
                                      kwargs,
                                      "zO",
                                      const_cast<char**>(kwList),
                                      &kw1_val,
                                      &kw2_val))
    {
        goto out;
    }

    // other code here

out:
    Py_XDECREF(empty);
    return retvalue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this worked. However I am still wondering why we need to workaround for only keywords handling.

Comment: You can make arguments keyword-only under Python 3 by [prefixing the format string with `"|$"`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#other-objects), but that will also make them optional; you seem to want mandatory keyword-only arguments, which are currently unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a classic X–Y problem here. Don't worry, I had the same one.

The Y here is `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`, when really the X is just "parsing only `kwargs` in the Python C API".

`kwargs` here is just a Python `dict()`, so really if we don't care about the positional arguments, we can just use the existing C API functions for dealing with `dict()`s, the [`PyDict_*` family of functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html).

So if we have a `PyCFunction` of the prototype:

```c
PyObject* Amit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds);
```

We know that `keywds` is a `PyDict`, in both Python 2 and Python 3. So we can just do e.g. this:

```c
PyObject* layerp = NULL;
if (keywds != NULL) layerp = PyDict_GetItemString(keywds, "layer");
```

`PyDict_GetItemString` will return `NULL` without setting an error, so we can just check `layerp` for `NULL` to know if we got an optional keyword argument or not.

Answer (score -1):

c++  sort by key

p::list l;

l.sort(*tuple(), **dict(make_tuple(make_tuple("key",
*[](object const& x){ return x["y"];}))));

Comment: How is this remotely relevant to the question?